# How to rotate object to always face mouse?

Tags: java, mouse, rectangles, drawing2d

I'm trying to make a game and I need the player(rectangle) to always be looking at the mouse, I have found some pages on this but I can't seem to understand the math.
Main:

```
 g2d.rotate(calculateRotation, x,y);
 g2d.fill(player);
 g2d.rotate(-calculateRotation, x,y);
```

Mouse Listener:

```
 int mx = e.getX();
 int mY = e.getY();

float rotation = Math.atan((mouseX-playerX)/(mouseY-playerY)); //<--- I don't know
```

[would it be something like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S9U3.png)

Comment: 2D or 3D?  Some more information would be good

Comment: @ Grantly, 2d, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You'll want to use `atan2`, not `atan`, otherwise you can't tell the difference between facing directly towards the mouse, and facing directly away from the mouse.

Comment: so math Math.atan2((mouseX-playerX)/(mouseY-playerY)); ?

Comment: `Math.atan2(mouseY-playerY, mouseX-playerX)`

Comment: Math.atan2(mouseY-playerY, mouseX-playerX) - Math.PI/2 was what finally worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use linear algebra- instead of using sines and cosines, you use vectors.

If you have **P1**=(x1,y1) (where the player is) and **P2**=(x2,y2) (where the mouse pointer is), then you have the vector **V**=(x2-x1,y2-y1)=(v1,v2), which has length v=|V|=sqrt(v1^2+v2^2). Then you have the versor (which is a vector of length=1) M=(v1/v,v2/v)=(m1,m2).

Then instead of computing an angle, you can rotate points by mapping (x,y)->(x* m1-y* m2, x* m2+y*m1).

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions

(and remember to take care in the case V=0)

Note: using atan is OK, but you will need to check the signs of x and y.. If they are both negative you'll find the wrong angle; and if one is positive and the other is negative, you still don't know if your arrow points NW or SE.

Comment: Would vector calcs be faster than sin/cos/tan ?  (I tend to think vectors are faster but value your findings)